# Как добавить сертификаты на сервер Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, сертификат

Сгенерировал бесплатные сертификаты для сайта. [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Запихнул все сертификаты в `/usr/local/share/ca-certificates/` 
и сделал 
`update-ca-certificates`

Но что то мне кажется что не так все просто

Comment: опишите, пожалуйста, чего именно вы ожидаете, и что неправильного происходит на самом деле.